# Questions not linked to account and can't accept answer

Tags: bug, answers, user-accounts

I have asked this question,

[Can I configure my Mac to store documents and pictures on iCloud only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346568)

And this question

[How can I clear pending iCloud Downloads?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346572)

I would like to accept an answer for the second, however even though I have 101 rep, on the questions I am only showing 1. On the first I asked the question as a guest but I did register before posting the second.

I used the same email address for both, which is my StackOverflow email address. Will these automatically link up over time?

Here's a screen shot showing my 100rep

[image]

Something odd has happened though as it shows 0 questions asked but just 10 minutes ago my second question was on there.

Ah here we are, if I click on my user name from the post it shows with the 101rep

[image]

Very odd bug!

Comment: The posts were made with an unregistered account it looks like...

Comment: Ah ok will these link up? it's the same email address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve had a quick look and it seems you’ve effectively (though unintentionally) created two accounts on Ask Different. I suspect when you first visited the site to ask your first question you created an unregistered account and then when you came back to ask the other question you ended up completing your registration which carried over an association bonus from your Stack Overflow account.

To resolve this you can ask to have the accounts merged as follows:

> ### I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
>
> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
>   sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I
>   need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange
>   Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can
>   confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email
>   address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

**Source:** [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Once the accounts are merged (at this time of year, allow some time for this to occur) you'll be able to accept the answer etc.

Comment: Thats done, thanks.